# OpenMP: pragma cancel for ON NUMA

Tags: c++, openmp, cancellation, numa

---------------------EDIT-------------------------

I have edited the code as follows:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, piold, err) shared(threshold_err) reduction(+:pi) schedule (static)
{
  for (i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++){ //1000000000//705035067
        piold = pi;
        pi += (((i&1) == false) ? 1.0 : -1.0)/(2*i+1);
        err = fabs(pi-piold);
        if ( err < threshold_err){
#pragma omp cancel for
        }

  }
}
  pi = 4*pi;
```

I compile it with LLVM3.9/Clang4.0. When I run it with one thread I get expected results with pragma cancel action (checked against non pragma cancel version, resulted in faster run).

But when I run it with threads >=2, the program goes into loop. I am run the code on NUMA machines. What is happening? Perhaps the cancel condition is not being satisfied! But then code takes longer than single thread non-pragma-cancel version!! FYI, it runs file when OMP_CANCELLATION=false.

---

I have following OpenMP code. I am using LLVM-3.9/Clang-4.0 to compile this code.

```
#pragma omp parallel private(i, piold, err) shared(pi, threshold_err)
{
#pragma omp for reduction(+:pi) schedule (static)
  for (i = 0; i < 10000000 ; i++){
        piold = pi;
        pi += (((i&1) == false) ? 1.0 : -1.0)/(2*i+1);
        #pragma omp critical
        {
        err = fabs(pi-piold);// printf("Err: %0.11f\n", err);
        }
        if ( err < threshold_err){
                printf("Cancelling!\n");
                #pragma omp cancel for
        }

  }
}
```

Unfortunately I do not think the `#pragma omp cancel for` is terminating the whole `for` loop. I am printing out the `err` value in the end, but again with parallelism it is confusing which value is being printed. The final value of `err` is smaller than `threshold_err`. The print cancelling is printing but in the very beginning of the program, which is surprising. The program keeps running after that!

How to make sure that this is correct implementation? BTW OMP_CANCELLATION is set to true and a small test program returns '1' for the corresponding function, omp_get_cancellation().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that the omp cancel is just a break signal, it notify so that no thread is created later. Threads which are still running will continue until the end. See http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/ and http://jakascorner.com/blog/2016/08/omp-cancel.html

In fact, in my opinion, I see your program product acceptable approximation. However, some variable can be keep in smaller scope. This is my suggestion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    long double pi = 0.0;
    long double threshold_err = 1e-7;
    int cancelFre = 0;

#pragma omp parallel shared(pi, threshold_err, cancelFre)
    {
#pragma omp for reduction(+:pi) schedule (static)
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){
            long double piold = pi;
            pi += (((i&1) == false) ? 1.0 : -1.0)/(2*i+1);
            long double err = std::fabs(pi-piold);
            if ( err < threshold_err){

#pragma omp cancel for
               cancelFre++;
            }

        }
    }

    std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << pi * 4 << " " << cancelFre;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, when I remove the `cancel for` loop part, code takes ~11 seconds with `i = 100000000`. But with `cancel for` in it takes forever that I have to abort it.

Comment: @algoProg The cancelFre is cancalling frequency, i put that right after ompcancel to count how many time the cancelling signal is sent (so that i know it just a signal after all). I'm pretty sure I can pass the loop. I also confirm on my laptop your code works, too. I just see you share quite many variables.

Comment: When I run it I get this error: `/tmp/stackoverflow_cancel-6237c0.o: In function `.omp_outlined.':
stackoverflow_cancel.cpp:(.text+0x408): undefined reference to `__sync_val_compare_and_swap_16'`

Comment: Also, when I run my code, I see cancel pragma cuts down the time, but I do not see the scaling with # of threads increasing. It is always same for all thread values

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I solved it. In my code above the problem was here:

`err = fabs(pi-piold);`

In the above line `pi` is changed before the following if condition is changed. Also multiple threads do the same. As I understand this makes program go in a deadlock.

I solved it by forcing only one thread, master, to do this check:

```
if(omp_get_thread_num()==0){
err = fabs(pi-piold);
if ( err < threshold_err){
#pragma omp cancel for
        }
}
```

I could have used `#pragma omp single` but it gave error about nested pragmas.

Here the performance suffers on low number of threads (1-4 are worse than normal sequential code). After that the performance improves. This is not the best solution and someone can surely improve upon this one.

Comment: I still don't get why you prefer to have i and piold outside the loop meanwhile they can be in loop scope. If they are just inside the loop, you won't worry about race condition since they are separated for each loop.

Comment: Please look at khôi nguyễn answer. It works!! Basically define `i` and `piold` inside the parallel pragma. Although 1-4 thread(s) performance still sucks against the sequential. 5-16 scale up linearly (16 is max num threads).